# HttpContext.Current is null in WebForms application after Cumulative Updates KB4576947 or KB4578974

Tags: asp.net, webforms, httpcontext

**UPDATE** - Rewriting the question based on new information found and a request for a reproducible sample.

*2020-09 Cumulative Update **Preview** for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 1903 for x64 ([KB4576947](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4576947/kb4576947-cumulative-update-for-net-framework))* was applied last night and changed/broke my code that uses `HttpContext.Current` because it is `null` when it is called in my code.

Updated: Now a 'non-preview' patch *October 13, 2020-[KB4578974](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4578974/kb4578974-cumulative-update-for-net-framework) Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10, version 1903, Windows Server, version 1903, Windows 10, version 1909, and Windows Server, version 1909* causes the same problem.  This patch applied on 10/14/2020 and resulted in the same behavior.

I confirmed this was the issue by testing a machine that did **not** have this update applied.  The code worked as expected, then I applied the same update and the code stopped working (failing the same way my machine does).

The update somehow changed the web site initialization code.  Below is a diff between the call stacks.  The top call stack is from the working machine without the update, and the bottom stack is from the failing machine.

[image]

You can see that the updated/failing machine is using `System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost` while the machine that is not updated and works is using `System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime`.

**To Reproduce**

1. Create a new C# Web Forms application (just pick the asp.net/web forms template).
2. After VS creates the template site, add a ProgrammaticConfigurationProvider.cs file to the root of the website.

```
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Xml;
    
    namespace WebApplication1
    {
        public class ProgrammaticConfigurationProvider : ProtectedConfigurationProvider
        {
            public override XmlNode Decrypt( XmlNode encryptedNode )
            {
                var configElement = encryptedNode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().First();
    
                switch ( configElement.Name )
                {
                    case "sessionState":
    
                        configElement.SetAttribute( "cookieName", "Test:" + ( HttpContext.Current.Session == null ? "Null" : "NotNull" ) );
                        break;
                }
    
                return configElement;
            }
    
            public override XmlNode Encrypt( XmlNode node ) => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

3. Update your web.config file, adding the following under the `configuration` element:

```
    <configProtectedData defaultProvider="ProgrammaticConfigurationProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="ProgrammaticConfigurationProvider" type="WebApplication1.ProgrammaticConfigurationProvider, WebApplication1" />
        </providers>
    </configProtectedData>
```

4. Update web.config, adding the following under `system.web` element:

```
    <sessionState configProtectionProvider="ProgrammaticConfigurationProvider">
        <EncryptedData>
            <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
        </EncryptedData>
    </sessionState>
```

Now when you run, `HttpContext.Current` will be null inside the `Decrypt` method.  We uninstalled the patch, and the code started working again as expected.

**Questions**

1. Why did I get a **preview** version of a patch?  I never really asked for it.
2. I'm going to uninstall this patch from my machine and assume it will start working again, but when the final version of this patch comes out, I wonder if it will behave the same way (breaking 100+ client sites of ours) or do those changes to the start of the call stack look like some sort of mistake that will be fixed?

Comment: I'm not even really sure I understand the question.  My knee jerk answer is yes, since this all worked yesterday and works on other machines.  All machines that work have the same call stack displayed in the top diff window.  Doesn't the call stack answer your question?  And a minimal reproducible example...not sure how to provide an entire web forms web application.  Is that even possible in stack overflow?

Comment: Any explanation for why this code base worked yesterday?  Or continues to work on other machines?  I'm updating my question wrt a windows update as well.

Comment: Well, it is exact same code base.  I strong suspect that windows update caused issue.  Desktop is on build 18362.592 (works), laptop is on 18362.1082 (doesn't work).  I read your link and still don't really know how to provide sample without an entire site.  Are you familiar with `ProtectedConfigurationProvider`?  I'd have to provide web.config and a site to reproduce since it is asp.net that calls it.  I have one more piece of information I put into question about laptop execution.  I assume you are the one voting to close/downvote.  I guess I'll just hope someone answers before closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222262/discussion-between-terry-and-mason).

Comment: Thanks for providing the info after I asked! Looks like there may be a bug in that Windows Update, or at least an unannounced change in behavior. Now that you have provided a [MCVE], it should be very easy for someone else to reproduce the behavior, and for MS to reproduce and fix a bug in the framework (if that's really what this is). There is still one close vote remaining on this question (not mine). If it does end up getting closed, feel free to ping me and I'll vote to re-open, as I believe your question is in good shape now.

Comment: @mason Do you have any idea of how to submit a bug to MS about this?  This patch keeps applying and I have to keep uninstalling every 4-5 days.  Frustrating but more worried about if this patch applies to a webserver hosting all our sites and breaks them all.

Comment: Try [contacting support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/).

Comment: Yeah, started there but end up at a pay for support page.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similary problem with my winform application who use dotnet 4.6.2.

Since this update was intalled, it's impossible to launch an application who require dotnet 4. I can see the application in the processus list, after 1 seconde, the processus is "suspended" and the application was closed...

Before this update, the application work normally.

Has anyone an idea?

Thank you

Christophe

Comment: Hoping for MS to see this, but I did have 'Feature update to Windows 10, version 2004' that was applied over the top of these patches that seemed to alleviate the problem.  You can try/confirm if you have the same success.

Comment: Actually KB4578968 applied again on top of my Feature update and broke things again.  Had to uninstall it.